# How get quantity of specific values in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have an multi-dimensional array. I want to get count of specific values in all arrays. This arrays in the main array depend on how many comments that I have added.

Here is my array:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(11) { 
    ["comment_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["user_Id"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["comment"]=> string(18) "Commented! edited!" 
    ["comment_datetime"]=> string(19) "2015-02-20 04:24:28" 
    ["update_at"]=> string(19) "2015-02-20 04:23:18" 
    ["user"]=> string(18) "Nishan Weerasinghe" 
    ["delete"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["username"]=> string(6) "Nishan" 
    ["picture_id"]=> NULL 
    ["picture"]=> NULL 
    ["picture_ext"]=> NULL 
  } 

  [1]=> 
  array(11) { 
    ["comment_id"]=> string(2) "48" 
    ["user_Id"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["comment"]=> string(4) "here" 
    ["comment_datetime"]=> string(19) "2015-02-23 12:58:00" 
    ["update_at"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["user"]=> string(18) "Nishan Weerasinghe" 
    ["delete"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["username"]=> string(6) "Nishan" 
    ["picture_id"]=> NULL 
    ["picture"]=> NULL 
    ["picture_ext"]=> NULL 
  } 
  [2]=> 
  array(11) { 
    ["comment_id"]=> string(2) "49" 
    ["user_Id"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["comment"]=> string(3) "dfg" 
    ["comment_datetime"]=> string(19) "2015-02-23 14:46:56" 
    ["update_at"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["user"]=> string(18) "Nishan Weerasinghe" 
    ["delete"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["username"]=> string(6) "Nishan" 
    ["picture_id"]=> NULL 
    ["picture"]=> NULL 
    ["picture_ext"]=> NULL 
  }
}
```

I want to get a count of how many `["delete"]=> 0` (answer should be 2 according to this ex.) are there in the main array.

Comment: where are your attempts? `count + array_filter` or good ol' foreach should suffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($results as $result){
    if($result['delete'] == "0"){
        $counter++;
    }
}
echo $counter;
```

Like the comment said a simple foreach and some math.

Answer (score 0):

just use foreach

```
$count=0;  
foreach($yourarray as $a){

  if($a['delete']=='1')
      $count++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with functions like this (Need PHP > 5.5.0):

```
echo array_count_values(array_column($array_string, 'delete'))[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply foreach loop as follows:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($yourarray as $counter){
    if($counter['delete'] == "0"){
        $count++;
    }
}
echo $count;
```